# Как в python 3 прочитать mp3 теги?

Tags: python, mp3

OS ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 2):

Есть такая библиотека - taglib, скорее всего она есть в Вашей убунте. В федоре он называется `python-tag`. Посмотреть [пример](http://taglib.github.io/api/).

Еще есть [eyed3](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/). Она также есть в федоре, так что скорее всего есть и убунте. В любом случае можно установить через [easy_install](http://habrahabr.ru/post/112332/).

Ну а для любителей, можно научиться парсить теги напрямую.